# Hiding HTML table columns with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to hide certain columns of a HTML template with JavaScript. Could anybody tell me how can I achieve this? I've tried giving IDs to the entire column TDs and then making `document.getElementById("ID").style.display = "none"` but it hides only the first TD.

Thank you.

Comment: An `id` has to be unique. Use `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are only supposed to be used uniquely, i.e. for one element only, therefore `getElementById` will only return 1 element, the first that matches. Try using a class instead and:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].style.display = "none";
```

**EDIT:** in jQuery mode on accident >:)

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the [jQuery Library](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)?

```
$('.tdCssClass').hide()
```

You could even go one step further and avoid the use of a cssClass:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide()
```

Would hide the 2nd column.

Comment: Still won't be able to hide all of the TDs that make up a given column this way.

Comment: Indeed, I realised my mistake shortly after submitting the answer.

Comment: Yep, and I like your second approach even better.  Downvote changed to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used jquery columnManager http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/columnmanager/ to allow user to easily show/hide table columns and it worked very well.